# upload_max_filesize - The perfect ubuntu server ISPConfig 3

Tags: php

I have looked at all the posts regarding upload_max_filesize but am still not making any progress!
any help would be appreciated.

I have set

```
vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

also

```
vi /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

ini_get('upload_max_filesize') reports 2M

mem limit is 128M
Where else do I need to go looking [apache config?].

In addition I cannot for the life get this to work either!

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
```

error_reporting is getting logged OK so at least I have some feedback.
chrome gives internal server error
firefox gives blank page.

I am using ubuntu server 10.10 ISPConfig 3 for learning about linux OS and php programming.

thanks

Answer (score 8):

this method works and is great if your setting for one website or for defaulting a servers cgi, if u have multiple sites, that need different settings for each site, your way will be  will be the default for all sites added to the panel.

If you have multiple sites

what u can do is set your default like above.

and for each individual site, you can add the custom values in the sites tab on ispconfig 3..

click your website in the sites tab in ispconfig, and then select the options tab for that website.

there should be two input boxes for setting custom php settings and apache2 for that site individually on ispconfig 3.

in The php custom add your custom settings

```
display_errors = On
post_max_size = 48M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
```

below is where u can manually edit php.ini's.

site wide cgi would be:

```
/etc/php5/cgi
```

sites on the configs individual php.ini, should b located in:

```
/var/www/conf/web1/php.ini
```

web1 above is for site #1 on the panel. for other sites it would b web 2, for site 2 and so on and so forth.

if want to make your own custom php.ini's you can place your own custom in:

```
/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d
```

also be sure to make a info.php using any text editor,

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

save as info.php

and upload it to your site to find exact locations of your php.ini 
if unsure where they are..

http://yourdomain.com/info.php

Answer (score 5):

My method is detailed here: http://www.breckers.co.uk/increase-php-maximum-upload-size-with-ispconfig/

Basically, in ISPConfig, set the following for the Custom php.ini settings under the sites>###site###>Options Tab

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 25M
```

Save, wait for the Jobqueue to finish (viewable under monitor)

And finally, restart the web service, or the server to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

update: upload_max_filesize
I managed to resolve my problem on my own. Setting the vars in the following file.

```
/etc/php5/cgi vi php.ini

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors = On
post_max_size = 48M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method def works great and helped me alot figuring things out. Manually always works best..

I just figured, ill add to your method, in-case any new members trying ispconfig, experienced the same problem like i did, and needed some more information on where setting things manually, or thru the panel can save them some time.

Glad it working out..